# The same results in DBSCAN and HDBSCAN?

Tags: hierarchical-clustering, dbscan, hdbscan

DBSCAN(epsilon, minPts = 2) is related to single linakge clustering and 
HDBSCAN(minPts = 2) is also related to single linkage clustering.

My question is that:
how I can obtain the same clustering results with these settings?
Or need to set other parameters in the HDBSCAN(there are many parameters in hdbscan library)?

Answer (score 1):

DBSCAN and HDBSCAN differ with respect to the treatment of border points, so it isn't really possible to get exactly the same answers from them. None the less there are some things you can do to get HDBSCAN results that are similar to DBSCAN.

```py
clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(
    min_samples=2, match_reference_implementation=True
).fit(X)
clusters = clusterer.single_linkage_.get_clusters(
    cut_distance=0.25, min_cluster_size=2
)
```

You can vary the `cut_distance` to desired values (the equivalent parameter in DBSCAN would be `epsilon`. Note that you can run HDBSCAN once, and then select any `cut_distance` you desire (a very cheap computation).